# Having issue with hover:after effect in IE8

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I have been trying to implement the css effect from this page here: http://sixrevisions.com/css/snazzy-hover-effects-using-css/

I have everything working fine except for the fix he posted for IE8; I added some conditional code so the fix is only used by <= IE8 & hence didn't include the CSS3 reset for normal browsers. However, the fix doesn't seem to have worked, all I see is the text & the text is wrapped at that.

You can see working examples here: http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_hover2/

My example I set up is here: http://www.condorstudios.com/example.html

Any ideas why mine isn't working? Only real differences I can see is he is using lists & he has his `a` tags set as `blocks`, I tried this but it messes my layout up.

Comment: If you change the position from relative to absolute, it works on IE8. Although it does not exactly looks like IE9. This is probally due to the transpency. If you change that, the two will be almost identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because you have added (and styled) an element between the container and the image (the `<span class="overlay">`. I think it is messing up the positioning in IE8. I have made a [**simple jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/M9Lnd/7/) that works in Chrome and IE8, based on the original example. Sorry I don't have IE9 or above so cannot verify if this will work.

The only problem I had was that `:hover` overlay element was too wide, so I added a `left:0;right:0` to the class. This may not be exactly what you are after but I hope it helps nonetheless :-)

Comment: I copied your styles exactly & replaced them into mine & for some reason mine still isn't working. :(

Comment: Does the demo work in IE8 for you? It's not just the CSS that I changed, I also removed the extra `<span>` and its associated style.

Comment: Oh ok. I'll check that out. Reason I used the span was because I didn't want the caption to span the width of the class, only the image. But yes, the demo worked in IE8, just no transparency is all.

Comment: You should be able to control the width of the caption with the CSS `left` and `right` on the hover class. The original demo also shows a solid background for IE8 as it does not support [rgba colors](http://caniuse.com/#search=rgba) which are used on the `background-color`

Comment: Yeah... I'll have a fiddle around & see if I can get the sizing/position of it correct. But after removing the span element it worked like the demo! :) Thanks very much! As for the transparency in IE gonna see if I can get something working by using filter: alpha(opacity=x).